# Advanced searching in Windows

Tags: windows, search

So I recently realized that I don't know how to find matlab file on my computer. All I know is that it has a .m extension.

I tried searching *.m in the search bar, however the search results are giving me every file that has an extension starting with the letter 'm', like *.mp3, *.mp4, *.mdl etc.

Is there a way to specify that only those files matching the exact extension to be shown.

p.s I know that I can complete the search and then sort them by type but it is still not the most perfect way.

Comment: maybe this might be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183659/windows-advanced-file-matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will exclude unwanted results:

```
*.m -mp3 -mp4 -mdl
```

and this will find only files ending in .m and not .m*:

```
"*.m"
```

I recommend [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/) on Windows search. I must however say that I am a longtime user of [FileLocator Lite a.k.a. Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) and I still prefer it to Windows search although I must admit the latter has grown to be an impressive tool. Nowadays I perform 99% of all my searches from the command line using [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org/)'s `find`, and `ag`.